# emacs, geiser, chiken scheme on windows setup help

Tags: window, repl, scheme

I want to go through SICP.
I installed Geiser and Chiken scheme

I set the scheme interpreter to be chiken

```
(setq scheme-program-name "C:/Program Files\ (x86)/Chicken Scheme/bin/csi.exe")
```

Then I run `M-x geiser` and choose `chicken` in the `Start Geiser for scheme implementation:` menu.

A new window with a new buffer is opened. The buffer is called `* Chiken REPL *`. 
But the buffer is empty. No promp no nothing.

Also, when I do `M-x run-scheme` it tells me `Spawning child process: invalid argument`.

Can anyone tell me please, how do I setup emacs, geiser, a scheme interpreter to run on windows?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a guess, your path to the Scheme implementation may be incorrect. Why do you think you need a backslash there? What do you want to quote/escape with it?

Now, go to `*scratch*` buffer and evaluate your path. You will see that it may be a bit surprising:

```
"C:/Program Files\ (x86)/Chicken Scheme/bin/csi.exe" 
⇒
"C:/Program Files(x86)/Chicken Scheme/bin/csi.exe"
```

Escaped space [is ignored in Emacs Lisp strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html).

I don't remember now what it's called on Windows, but try this:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Chicken Scheme/bin/csi.exe"
```